# Building multiple projects when pushing to a PR in Jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, pull-request

I've been trying to find a way to build multiple projects when pushing(syncing) to a PR on github. We have multiple projects(**projectA** or **projectB**) that are dependant on one main project(let's call it **mainProject**).

When changing the signature of a method in **mainProject** (that are used in **projectA**), I would need Jenkins to build **mainProject** first, then build **projectA**.

The build environment is fine. What I need is to fetch the corresponding branch on the other dependant projects.

So let's say I

1. Modify **projectA** and push to branch name **3333**
2. Change a signature in **mainProject** and push to branch name **3333** .
3. Open PR in github for **projectA** and **mainProject** both with branch name **3333** to **development** branch.

Whenever I sync my previously created PR on **projectA**, I would like to jenkins to :

1. Fetch **mainProject** 3333 and fetch **projectA** 3333.
2. From there, i'll manage the building...

We are using

- [Github PR plugin builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin)
- [Github plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin)

I see there is a *Add repository* box, but I can't seem to get it to fetch the mainProject.

[image: repo]

The Repository URL is the ssh .git url from our github repository.

I've also seen this plugin :
Multiple SCMs Plugin (can't post the link because I don't have enough reputation!)

Does anyone had the chance to try that?

Thanx in advance.